# How can I use Regex to match JavaScript event names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm working on a script that's injected into a page and has several custom events that notify me of content updates/DOM changes so that I can respond accordingly.

Currently, the events are encoded to provide a bit of extra information, for example `Event:pageChange:[page number]` and this is making it a bit tricky to listen for these events, particularly ones around user search where the event name includes user-input text.

Is there a way to match events using regex?

Alternatively, is there a way to watch all events coming or originating from an element and then match from there? (The custom events come from the `document` so I assume I'll get a huge amount of events bubbling up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I dont think it can be matched using regex. Even if it did work somehow it could potentially cause performance drops and event blocking violations. Instead I would suggest you use that `Event:pageChange:[page number]` as `Event:pageChange` with extraParams. Refer to [jQuery Trigger Docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for more information.